# JSON Generator generate the JSON with backslash

Tags: rest-api, apex-webservice, jsongenerator

I am using the JSON Generator class to create the JSON.
but in response backslash get added.

Result:

```
"{\"Id\":\"a171j000000WDQCAA4\",\"Name\":\"Q-00123\"}"
```

Could you please suggest me how we generate the Json with out backslash.

Method:

```
public static string responseCall(Id QId){ 
    List<SBQQ__Quote__c> q=[select Id , Name from SBQQ__Quote__c where Id=:QId];   
    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(false);
    
    for(SBQQ__Quote__c quoteDtls : q){      
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('Id', quoteDtls.Id);
        gen.writeStringField('Name', quoteDtls.Name);
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

    system.debug(gen.getAsString());

    return gen.getAsString();           
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add code or metadata to reproduce the problem.

Comment: public static string responseCall(Id QId){
         List<SBQQ__Quote__c> q=[select Id , Name from SBQQ__Quote__c where Id=:QId];
            
         JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(false);

         for(SBQQ__Quote__c quoteDtls : q){      
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField('Id', quoteDtls.Id);
            gen.writeStringField('Name', quoteDtls.Name);
            gen.writeEndObject();
            }
        system.debug(gen.getAsString());
     return gen.getAsString();           
    }

Answer (score 0):

This code is not responsible for the backslashes. I tested this in my developer org. Note that, however, it also won't generate valid JSON, as you need to wrap the entire thing in an array (writeStartArray and writeEndArray).

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(false);
gen.writeStartArray();
for(SBQQ__Quote__c quoteDtls : q){      
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField('Id', quoteDtls.Id);
    gen.writeStringField('Name', quoteDtls.Name);
    gen.writeEndObject();
}
gen.writeEndArray();
system.debug(gen.getAsString());
return gen.getAsString();
```

You'll need to look elsewhere in your code to figure out where the escapes (the `\` characters) are coming from.

Comment: can you call this code using postman.
I mean create the  post method and return should be string see what exactly return

Comment: @user3652558 Yes, your post method may be the problem, depending on a variety of factors. That is what I attempted to convey in my answer. This code is just fine, it's your main method that's encoding the JSON string a second time.